Alternative method for generating random points on an n-sphere
It appears that the common way of generating random points uniformly on the surface of an $n$-sphere is by picking $n+1$ values randomly from a standard normal distribution, then dividing them all by the sum of their squares to normalize them.
Something about this strikes me as inelegant. First, I would expect that only $n$ random values would be needed to generate such a point. Second, although the probability of this happening is incredibly slim in practice, it is possible to obtain the zero vector, which cannot be normalized (and thus resampling is required).
I've come up with an alternative procedure that avoids these problems:

Pick $n$ random values from a uniform distribution on the unit interval $[0, 1)$.
Use those random values to divide the unit interval into $n+1$ segments.
Take the square roots of the sizes of the intervals, applying a randomly chosen sign.

So my questions are:

Is there any reason why this method would not generate the expected uniform distribution of points on a sphere?
If this does generate the correct distribution, why isn't this method used in practice? I would expect the limiting factor would be calculating square roots.


Spherical coordinates would be way more suited since they are compatible with intergration but it requires a lot of computations. Taking roots is also costly in computations

Regarding your two objections to the trick of using the normal distribution for the job:

The $n$-sphere is embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Normalizing cuts the dimension down by 1.
You can, mathematically speaking, implement randn such that it will never return 0, and it wouldn't mathematically interfere with the construction. Floating point limitations are more impactful than that.

Regarding your method:
It's just not uniform on the sphere. Look at $n=1$. In this case your method produces $(\sqrt{U},\sqrt{1-U})$ where $U$ is uniform. So for example $P(X>1/\sqrt{2})$ should be $1/4$ (it is the arc from $\theta=-\pi/4$ to $\theta=\pi/4$). But with your method it's $1/2$.
